# Is it possible to have multiple actions for the action attribute of h:commandLink?

Tags: spring, jsf, commandlink

Is it possible to have multiple actions for the `action` attribute of `h:commandLink` tag? I want to perform two actions while clicking on the link rendered by `h:commandLink` tag. An action needs to be performed in a Spring bean, and a pop up window displaying a certain webpage.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to call two methods in `action` attribute. And I don't think this is major disadvantage. Encapsulate logic in one method in managed bean, and call those to actions from that method.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to have multiple actions in a commandLink action. If you want to perform some logic **and** to display a pop up window just wrap your logic in a single method, and at the bottom add a FacesMessage to the the context. You can do an AJAX partial refresh of the h:messages component to show the message as a "pop up" without reloading the page.